# Unique constraint between several columns derived from the same one to many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not sure if I titled this correctly or if it is even possible.

I have three columns that are populated from the same one to many relationship from another table.

For example:

```
User_Id | Security Question 1 | Security Question 2 | Security Question 3
```

And a table of questions:

```
Id | Question
1  | Are you x?
2  | Are you y?
3  | Are you z?
```

When a row is written into the first table it requires a security question from the second table. However, the possible choices are all the questions from the second table. I want to enforce a restriction that any user didn't pick any question twice.

How can I do this? Should this be relegated to my application code?

Comment: So you already have some sort of constraint that only allows questions from the question table and you just need a `CHECK` constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little tricky.  Often, it is not reasonable to store the same entity in multiple columns.  This is a case where it might make sense.

You can readily do what you want with a check constraint:

```
alter table t add constraint check_t_security
    check (SecurityQuestion1 <> SecurityQuestion2 and
           SecurityQuestion2 <> SecurityQuestion3 and
           SecurityQuestion3 <> SecurityQuestion1 
          );
```

The logic is similar but more cumbersome if `NULL` values are allowed for the questions.  You would have to specify if a user could have more than one `NULL` value.

You can shorten the logic to:

```
alter table t add constraint check_t_security
    check (SecurityQuestion1 not in (SecurityQuestion2, SecurityQuestion3) and
           SecurityQuestion2 not in (SecurityQuestion3) 
          );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you normalize your table it is pretty straight-forward.

```
create table t (
  UserId int
, QuestionOrdinal tinyint
, QuestionId int
, constraint uc_UserId_QuestionOrdinal unique (UserId, QuestionOrdinal)
, constraint uc_UserId_QuestionId unique (UserId, QuestionId)
);
insert into t values (1,1,1),(1,2,2);
insert into t values (1,3,1) -- constraint violation
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/FEHY66465